# How to disable every navigation in WebBrowser?

Tags: c#, winforms, hyperlink, browser

I have a `WebBrowser` control which I dinamically refresh/change url based on user input. I don't want to let the user to navigate, so I set `AllowNavigation` to false. This seems to be OK, however the below link is still "active":

```
<a href=# onClick="javascript:window.close()">Close Page</a>
```

The issue here is: If the user clicks it, and confirms closure in the pop-up window I can't manage `WebBrowser` anymore. Looks like it is closed though the last page is still visible. Also I can't remove this link as the site is not managed by me.

Disable the control? Nope, I have to allow the user to highlight and copy text from the webpage.
Do I have any other option to disable literally ALL links?

@TaW: here is my code based on yours. So I have to set the url from my code and call a custom one:

```
button_click()
{
    webBrowser1_load_URL("http://website/somecheck.php?compname=" + textBoxHost.Text);
}
```

Here it is the function:

```
private void webBrowser1_load_URL(string url)
{
    string s = GetDocumentText(url.ToString());
    s = s.Replace(@"javascript:window.close()", "");
    webBrowser1.AllowNavigation = true;
    webBrowser1.DocumentText = s;
}
```

The rest is exaclty what's in your answer:
    private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender,

```
WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.AllowNavigation = false;
}
public string GetDocumentText(string s)
{
    WebBrowser dummy = new WebBrowser(); //(*)
    dummy.Url = new Uri(s);
    return dummy.DocumentText;
}
```

Still it's not working. Please help me to spot the issue with my code.

Comment: Please use the 2nd Replace command from the last comment,  `("javascript:window.close", "javascript:window.focus")` and also __do use the debugger__ to check the resulting string. (You can copy it out of the debugger and have a closer look at it.) The copy link can't still be there, after all! (If the page is on the Web, I can have a look, too..)

Comment: I modified the replacement, still no go. The link is there, and it's working as well. It's only available on the corporate intranet so I can't let you check it. But there is nothing else related. This is the whole part for this Close link:
`<p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0" align="center"><a href=# onClick="javascript:window.close()">
<font size="2">Close Page</font></a></p>`

Comment: This is weird! The next thing to try could be to break after the Replace, and modify the string s manually in the Debugger. You need to find out if the Replace or the loading of the Text is the issue.. I can't believe there could be a caching problem with assigning DocumentText.

Comment: Wow, it's strange. `s` is empty before the replacement.

Comment: Like it couldn't get the content of the php using `GetDocumentText()`

Comment: Any further idea? I can't find out why it fails reading the page.

Comment: Well then go into our GetDocumentText function and see if it get at the text. Is the resulting page empty or is the link still there??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have control over the loading of the pages you could grab the pages' text and change the code to disable rogue scripts. The one you showed can simply be deleted. Of course you might have to forsee more than the one..

Obviously this could be eased if you could do without javascript alltogether, but if that is not an option go for those that do real or pseudo-navigation..

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  webBrowser1.AllowNavigation = false;
}

private void loadURL_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  webBrowser1.AllowNavigation = true;
  string s = File.ReadAllText(textBox_URL.Text);
  s = s.Replace("javascript:window.close()", "");
  webBrowser1.DocumentText = s;
}
```

If the pages are not in the file system, the same trick should work, for instance by loading the URL into a dummy WebBrowser like this:

```
private void cb_loadURL_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string s = GetDocumentText(tb_URL.Text);
    s = s.Replace("javascript:window.close()", "");
    webBrowser1.AllowNavigation = true;
    webBrowser1.DocumentText = s;
}

public string GetDocumentText(string s) 
{ 
    WebBrowser dummy = new WebBrowser(); //(*)
    dummy.Url = new Uri(s);
    return dummy.DocumentText;
}
```

Note: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150014/load-in-memory-text-into-webbrowser-control) post you can't set the `DocumentText` quite as freely as one would think; probably a bug.. Instead of creating the dummy each time you can also move the (*) line to class level. Then, no matter how many changes you had to make, you would always have an unchanged version, th user could e.g. save somewhere..

Comment: The page is not stored locally. I tried your second shot, but the close link is still working properly.

Comment: Hm, it remains dead here, as expected. Try to debug to the Replace command and check that it is doing its thing. It may be a spelling problem.. even a blank in the close() parenthesis etc will break the code. Making it more robust to such minor differences would be one thing to keep in mind. I'm no good at RegExes, though, so I won't try that ;-)

Comment: JavaScript being case-sensitive, maybe this would be an improvement: `s = Replace("javascript:window.close", "javascript:window.focus");`. No blanks should be able to sneak in there.. __But__ then there are: `window.blur(), window.home()` and `window.open()`..

Comment: I've just added the code based on your answer to the question. Please check it.